# Text size selected in combo

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

As we can see on lots of web site : we can increase or decrease size of font. Like on this example : http://blog.creonfx.com/examples/javascript/dynamic-font-resize.html

Is this possible in GWT ?
So could I change general (= all widgets) font size dynamically by choosing a size in a combo (1, 2, 3) like on the image ?

[image]

Comment: Which type is the widget you want to change the size font from the combo selection?

Comment: I give more details in the question part... so do you have some suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending of the widget, for example the ones which have a content property which could be set with Html should be feasible I think....
If you can get a reference to the DOM element you want to change you would probably be able to change the style via some specific javascript.
But in any case I don't think there is a direct way of doing it and on any widget.
You can have a look to [this thread](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=15814&highlight=style%20dynamically) also which indicate this fact.

Comment: Need a global change not on only each widget... Maybe I'll try to add a class on BODY element or on the RootPanel